# How to find complexity of this nested for loop code according to Big O notation?

Tags: big-o, code-complexity

I found this code on my algorithms book but i couldn't understand the example.

Here is the code:

```
for(i=1;i<n-1;i++){
   for(j=n;j>i+1;j--){
      if(a[j-1]>a[j]){
         t=a[j-1];
         a[j-1]=a[j];
         a[j]=t;
    }
  }
}
```

Now and  according to book the complexity of the each part calculated like this [image: this]

and also the big O of the entire code calculated like this [image: this]

But i couldnt understand it .Can you please explain the complexity of this code to me? especially the part where it calculated the complexity as `O(n/2)` because of term `j>i+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this seem to come up here fairly often.  Here is your swapping code:

```
for (i=1; i < n-1; i++) {
    for (j=n; j > i+1; j--) {
        if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
            t = a[j-1];
            a[j-1] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate that the outer loop will take `N-1` steps.  The inner loop will take somewhere between `N-2` and `1` steps.  We can approximate this further by saying that the outer loop has `N` steps and the inner loop will take between 1 and `N` steps.  On average, then, the inner loop will take `N/2` steps to complete.

This works out to `O(N*N/2)` = `O(N^2)`.  So the swapping code you showed us is `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop executes i=1 to n-2 that is, n-2 times. The inner loop executes (n-3), (n-4),......, n-(n-1) that is in total n-3+n-4+n-5+...+2+1 times. When i=1 inner loop executes (n-3) times, when i=(n-2) inner loop executes 1 time. That will give (n-3)*(n-2)/2. When we consider the if condition and it's body then for each execution of inner loop, 3 statements execute. In total that will give (n-3)*(n-2)/2 * 3. There is no need to consider (n-3) as (n-3), instead take it as n and do not consider **3 and /2. Complexity calculation using such a method is an approximation. So complexity is of the order of n*n. O(n^2).

When you see a loop then consider it as n steps. If there are inner loops then multiply it. For one loop O(n). For two loops O(n*n). For three loops O(n**n*n) etc.